# Prove that the absolute value of the difference of two invariant distributions on a Markov chain is invariant

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, markov-chains

If we have $a(x)$, $b(x)$ which are invariant distributions on a Markov chain $X_n$ with state space $S$, how can I prove that $|a(x)-b(x)|$ is also invariant?

I know that I must show that:

$\sum_{x \in S} |a(x)-b(x)|p(x,y) = c(y)$

where $p(x,y)$ is the transition function for $X_n$.

So what I did was I partitioned $S$ such that $A \subset S$ where if $a(x) \geq b(x)$ then $x \in A$. So that gets me:

$\sum_{x \in A}a(x)p(x,y) - \sum_{x\in A}b(x)p(x,y) - \sum_{x\in A^c}a(x)p(x,y)+\sum_{x\in A^c}b(x)p(x,y)$

But I do not know where to go from here... My first thought was to combine summations from complementary sets but I am not sure how to do that to make the whole thing either constant or constant as a function of $y$.

Thank you.

Comment: Each irreducible class of your Markov chain has at most one associated "extremal invariant distribution" associated with its time average limiting behavior given you start in a state of that class.  Further, distinct extremal invariant distributions have disjoint support sets.  Then you can prove that any invariant distribution is a convex combination of extremal distributions.

Comment: Also, you do not want to show $\sum_{x \in S} |a(x)-b(x)|p(x,y)=c(y)$, a function of $y$, that is in fact always true since $x$ is a dummy variable that is summed out.  You want to show that, if $d^T$ is the transpose of the vector, then $d^T = d^T P$ (where $P$ is the transition probability matrix).

Comment: In particular, you want to show that $\sum_{x \in S} |a(x)-b(x)|p(x,y) = |a(y)-b(y)|$ for all $y \in S$.

Comment: Well, I have received no feedback so far.  Do you agree that the goal is in fact as described in my last comment?  And that $\sum_{x \in S} |a(x)-b(x)|p(x,y)$ is in fact _always_ a function of $y$ alone (regardless of the properties of $a(x), b(x),p(x,y)$), and so proving it is a function of $y$ alone cannot be the goal?

Answer (score 0):

For a vector $h = (h_1,…,h_n)$, define $|h|$ as the entrywise absolute value: 
$$ |h| = (|h_1|, …, |h_n|) $$

Now,  for example, if $z=(1/2,1/2,0,0,0)$ and $w=(0,0,1,0,0)$ then for any scalars $\alpha, \beta$ we have: 
$$ |\alpha z + \beta w| = |\alpha| z + |\beta| w $$
and if $z^T = z^T P$ and $w^T = w^T P$ then: 
$$ |\alpha z + \beta w|^T P = |\alpha|z^T P + |\beta| w^T P = |\alpha | z^T + |\beta| w^T = |\alpha z + \beta w|^T $$

This example can be generalized to see that the absolute value of linear combinations of invariant distributions with disjoint support indices are also invariant  under multiplication by $P$.